# About locally convex space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Is a Banach space a locally convex space? Why?**

Recall A locally convex space is a linear topological space in which the topology has a base consisting of convex sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to define a space $X$ to be locally convex if there is a collection $\{p_{\alpha}\}$ of seminorms on $X$ so that the topology on $X$ coincides with the initial topology of the seminorms; in particular, the sets

$$\bigcap_{i = 1}^n \{p_{\alpha_i}(x) < \epsilon\}$$

form a base for the neighborhoods of zero.

In the case of a normed space, the family can be taken to consist of the norm (which is also a seminorm); the assumption that the space is Banach isn't necessary.

---

The equivalence of the two definitions is discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_space#Equivalence_of_definitions).

Answer (score 2):

In a Banach space (or indeed in any normed space), the topology has a base consisting of open balls, i.e., sets of the form $\{x:\Vert x-a\Vert<\epsilon\}$, and these are convex because of the triangle inequality.